# How to validate date field in Azure Data Factory Mapping Flows in Conditional split operator

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Source date fields coming to my flow looks like a regular date in YYYY-MM-DD format. I'd like to use Conditional split operator to validate if a particular column can be converted to date column.

I was trying to use something like this:

```
isNull(toDate($column_list[3])) == false()
```

But it does not work as expected -> it rejects every single row....

Can you help?

Comment: As you said , the coming data are regular date in YYYY-MM-DD format, it's a valid date data(string) and that will cause the expression `isNull(toDate($column_list[3]))` always return `false`(not null), then 'false()==false() ' also will always return `true`.

Comment: Hi @Konrad Samulski, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. If you have any other concerns, please feel free to let me know, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my experience, if the coming data(we consider it's a string data in default) is not a valid date string, the result of `toDate()` function will return `NULL`.

Ref this example:
[image]

As you said , the coming data are regular date in YYYY-MM-DD format, it's a valid date data(string) and that will cause the expression `isNull(toDate($column_list[3]))` always return `false`(not null), then `false()==false()` also will always return true.

The expression will always return true, that why it doesn't work ad expected.